# How to switch from Static block to "Manage Categories"

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento (1.7) and want setup an ecommerce site. I have downloaded a theme and started working on it. I am following online help and setup the store. In the user guide it talks about Catelog->Manage Categories to create new categories and sub categories. I followed the instructions as it is. But the frontend is pulling categories tab from the cms-> static block named "top_nav"

Where I should make the change so that categories and subcategories are picked from what I set in Catelog->Manage Categories.

Comment: What theme you are using?

Comment: This not much info you need to go there

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048162/how-to-switch-from-static-block-to-manage-categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question really depends on what the creators of the theme have done to remove the old navigation and implement their new one which is controlled by a CMS block. However I have done my best to give you some general guidelines on how you could solve your issue.

First we need to see what template files are currently writing the existing main menu.

**Turning on Magento Template Path Hints.**

1. Visit System >> Configuration >> Developer.
2. Chances are, your current configuration scope (top left hand corner)
   is set to “Default Config.” You cannot setup Magento Template Path
   Hints globally.
3. You’ll need to set the Configuration Scope to a website or store configuration. (e.g. Default Store View). See below image.
4. Once the Current Configuration Scope is set to a store or website
   view, you need to change Template Path Hints to Yes. This is found
   under the Debug heading.
   [image: magento - turning on template path hints]

**Identifying what template is calling the existing main menu**

5. Now visit your website (you may need to clear cache), above each section you will see a path to the template that section is using. Note the template name mentioned where your menu is. This is the template that is calling the CMS block menu.
6. In the below screenshot we see the file is top.phtml and its inside
   header.phtml.
   [image: magento - template hints on frontend]
7. To disable this main menu from being used go to the template, in this case either header.phtml or top.phtml and comment out/remove the reference. Keep in mind we will need to add the default menu reference back in here so keep the files open.

**Bringing back magento's default menu**

8. In your current themes layout folder (app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/layout/) open page.xml.
9. Find the section that starts with the this block opening:`<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">` and then add the below code inside it if it doesnt not already exist:

   ```
   <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
   <label>Navigation Bar</label>
   <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
   </block>
   ```
10. Open your header template (app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/page/html/header.phtml) and add the below code where you want the menu to appear.
        `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>`

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because of something which the custom theme is doing, and there are a number of ways in which it could be doing it; best bet would be to ask the theme author.